# How to exclude objects from cloth's collision?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I have a bed in a room with lots of objects. I'd like to put a sheet over the bed by simulating the sheet as cloth falling over the bed (which has collision enabled).

Problem is, I have many other objects around the bed which has collision enabled.

I tried to hide everything except the bed and the sheet, but the sheet is still affected by the collision of the other objects.

I would prefer not to move the bed out of the way, nor disable collision on the other objects because I need it for other simulations.

Is there a way to specify or exclude objects that the sheet can collide with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**. This is possible with *Collision groups*.

1. Make a [*Group*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting#Grouping_objects) of the objects you want the sheet to collide with. (select objects and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>)
2. Set that group in the cloth collision settings for the sheet under *Cloth Collision > Collision Group*:

   [image]

Now the sheet object will only collide with the objects in the group *Bed*.